# Jupyter notebook terminal starts up at /root folder. How can I change the default path to /nfs in dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyter

I am using Dockerfile to run shell script of jupyter notebook. When this jupyter terminal starts up, it's starting at /root path, but I want terminal to start with default path /nfs.
What change can be made in the Dockerfile such that this terminal starts at /nfs path ?

Comment: you can add below entry in your dockerfile
`
WORKDIR /nfs
`

Answer (score 1):

you can add below entry in your dockerfile so everything after mentioned the WORKDIR step would be in the directory you have mentioned.

```
WORKDIR /nfs
```

Comment: Thank you.. will try it out

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am setting the variable to /tf-project, yet it opens in /tf. Any ideas on what is happening?